# Deleting all rows if the date is invalid

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, date, dictionary

I have 26 elements in the datas dictionary, all are list. I am extracting the lists within a date range.

- If the date is invalid it throws error. In dt_dates line I need to delete invalid row in all lists including date.

```py
dates = datas['Date']
serials = datas['Serial_No']
dt_dates = [datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for date in dates]
in_between_dates = []
in_between_serial = []
for i,d in enumerate(dt_dates,0):
    if d.date() >= Start_Date.get_date() and d.date() <= End_Date.get_date():
        in_between_dates.append(d)
        in_between_serial.append(serials[i])
```

Comment: Please read and follow [mre] and [ask]. Your code is erroneous, incomplete and the whole thing is unclear without at least a piece of the data you operate on.

Comment: i think now the question looks good for answering

Comment: `NameError` on: `datas, Start_Date, End_Date` (and missing imports). "# 24 lines like this" make no sense to me (unlesss you somehow parse 24 _different kind of dateformatstrings_?) - please READ [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dates = datas['Date']
serials = datas['Serial_No']

#24 lines like these
print(len(dates))
dt_dates = [datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for date in dates]

#Simulate invalid date here
in_between_dates = []
in_between_serial = []

#24 lines like these
for i,d in enumerate(dt_dates,0):
    try:
        if d.date() >= Start_Date.get_date() and d.date() <= End_Date.get_date():
            in_between_dates.append(d)
            in_between_serial.append(serials[i])
    except:
        print('Invalid date skipped')
```